# AWS CloudWatch and EC2 Role + Policy

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cloudwatch

I've followed a [great tutorial](https://martinjt.me/2020/02/16/serilog-and-cloudwatch-with-inbuilt-credentials) by Martin Thwaites outlining the process of logging to AWS CloudWatch using Serilog and .Net Core.

I've got the logging portion working well to text and console, but just can't figure out the best way to authenticate to AWS CloudWatch from my application. He talks about inbuilt AWS authentication by setting up an IAM policy which is great and supplies the JSON to do so but I feel like something is missing. I've created the IAM Policy as per the example with a LogGroup matching my appsettings.json, but nothing comes though on the CloudWatch screen.

My application is hosted on an EC2 instance. Are there more straight forward ways to authenticate, and/or is there a step missing where the EC2 and CloudWatch services are "joined" together?

**More Info:**
Policy `EC2CloudWatch` attached to role `EC2Role`.

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "VisualEditor0",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                ALL EC2 READ ACTIONS HERE
            ],
            "Resource": "*"
        },
        {
            "Sid": "LogStreams",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "logs:CreateLogStream",
                "logs:DescribeLogStreams",
                "logs:PutLogEvents"
            ],
            "Resource": "arn:aws:logs:*:*:log-group:cloudwatch-analytics-staging
:log-stream:*"
        },
        {
            "Sid": "LogGroups",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "logs:DescribeLogGroups"
            ],
            "Resource": "arn:aws:logs:*:*:log-group:cloudwatch-analytics-staging"

        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: " created the IAM Policy" - did you attach the policy to your instance role? Or how do you provide aws credentials to your app?

Comment: @Marcin I've updated my question with more information. The policy is above with CloudWatch Read/Write as well as EC2 Read. This policy is used by an EC2 role. Do I need to attach that EC2 role to the specific instance, or what?

Comment: Yes, the role needs to be assigned to the EC2 instance: https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/assign-iam-role-ec2-instance/

Comment: @DennisTraub hey there we go! It works. I just needed to attach the IAM role. Do you know what the minimum privileges to EC2 are, perhaps? I've got it on `Read All` which seems a bit excessive.

Comment: Since it helped solve the issue, I've added my above comment as an answer for you to accept. Regarding your question which specific permissions to apply: I agree that you should only provide the necessary permissions to any role. This is also called the *Principle of Least Privilege*. However, *which* specific permissions you need very much depends and can't be answered without diving deep into your specific use case.

Comment: @DennisTraub I'll toggle off each `read privilege` until it breaks. Bit of a schlep, but it'll eventually get to the ideal state.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to effectively apply the permissions, you need to [assign the role](https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/assign-iam-role-ec2-instance/) to the EC2 instance.